# KSS Styleguide with Angular 4

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, knyle-style-sheet

I have an Angular 4 app that we use SCSS with and we would like to use [KSS Styleguide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kss) to automatically create a styleguide. The issue is that KSS needs to be pointed at a compiled CSS file so it can show previews of the styles. However, because Angular 4 is using webpack, the styles are dumped into a JS file instead of a .css file.

One thought I had was to just create a separate task to build KSS and compile the SASS into a css file used specifically for KSS. I want to make sure it gets compiled the same way as Angular compiles it however. I have no idea how to create this task.

Or maybe there is an alternative version of KSS built for Angular?

**UPDATE:**

I tried the solution that @jonrsharpe gave but I'm receiving errors that it can't find the css file. Here is what I have added to package.json

```
"prestyleguide": "ng build --extract-css true",
"styleguide": "kss --css dist/styles.bundle.css ...",
```

And here is there error message I get

```
C:\CARE\proto1-dev-hancojw\angular>npm run prestyleguide

> CARE-Prototype@0.0.1 prestyleguide C:\CARE\proto1-dev-hancojw\angular
> ng build --extract-css true

Hash: 4bfb83655402eaeeeb22
Time: 18197ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 287 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 145 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.css, styles.bundle.css.map (styles) 122 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.66 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

C:\CARE\proto1-dev-hancojw\angular>npm run styleguide

> CARE-Prototype@0.0.1 prestyleguide C:\CARE\proto1-dev-hancojw\angular
> ng build --extract-css true

Hash: 4bfb83655402eaeeeb22
Time: 17213ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 287 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 145 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.css, styles.bundle.css.map (styles) 122 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.66 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

> CARE-Prototype@0.0.1 styleguide C:\CARE\proto1-dev-hancojw\angular
> kss --css dist/styles.bundle.css ...

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\CARE\proto1-dev-hancojw\angular\...'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! CARE-Prototype@0.0.1 styleguide: `kss --css dist/styles.bundle.css ...`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the CARE-Prototype@0.0.1 styleguide script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HancoJW\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-14T15_03_17_013Z-debug.log

C:\CARE\proto1-dev-hancojw\angular>
```

I have verified that the css file is being created, its like it can't find it though.

**UPDATE 2**

Don't forget to add the remaining bits of the task, --source and --destination. Added those in and now it's working great!

Comment: Are you using the Angular CLI?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Angular CLI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide an option to `ng build` to exclude the CSS from the JS bundling, then pass that separate CSS file to KSS along with any other options you have. In `package.json`, I ended up with something like:

```
"prestyleguide": "ng build --extract-css true",
"styleguide": "kss --css styles.bundle.css ...",
"poststyleguide": "cp dist/styles.bundle.css styleguide/",
```

Note that this will only include the global styles, not the component-specific encapsulated styling. Also note that the `css` options are *URLs*, not paths, which is why I copy the stylesheet into the styleguide output directory for deployment.

See the commit where I added it to my own Angular project: [`textbook/salary-stats@87dcb50`](https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/commit/87dcb50e7e1ac7991894edb897918e6718f1247f) (deployed result: [Salary Stats Style Guide](http://salary-stats-style-shirtless-albertype.cfapps.pez.pivotal.io/)).

Comment: Looked like good potential but I got an error when trying it. See updated note in original question.

Comment: Yup sorry was being stupid there... Added the --source and --destination and it works great now! Thanks!

Comment: @BlueCaret note that the `css` option is for *URLs*, not paths - I've updated my answer and linked to a commit that shows how to add the styleguide in a deployable way.