# kss-node Style Guide with Angular 2 including component styles and script

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to generate a [KSS styleguide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kss) in an Angular 2 project. Setting up KSS and creating the style guide with global styles and no functionality is no problem (as described here [KSS Styleguide with Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092090/kss-styleguide-with-angular-4)).

This solution has two disadvantages:

1. It means that all component styles have to be imported into the
   global styles.scss to be styled.
2. More complex components are not working because no JavaScript is
   included.

Is there a way to create a KSS style guide that shows working and styled Angular components?
I am playing around with loading bundled Angular files from AOT compilation mode into the KSS template file but it does not seem to work. Or is there a way to base the entire KSS Styleguide on Angular?